# Jquery countup plugin using "jQuery Boilerplate"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm new to Jquery plugin creation. Following jquery plugin is created using jQuery Boilerplate. It just do a count-up and notify when count-up finished.
I want to have a function to restart count-up by setting counter to 0;
I dont understand how to call that reset function

```
  ;(function ( $, window, undefined ) {


        var pluginName = 'countup',
            document = window.document,
            defaults = {
                countSince: new Date(),
                countUpTo:120,
                notifyAfter:110,
                onExpire:function() {

                },          
            };

        // The actual plugin constructor
        function Plugin( element, options ) {
            this.element = element;
            this.options = $.extend( {counter:0}, defaults, options) ;
            this._defaults = defaults;
            this._name = pluginName;
            this.init();
        }

        Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
            this.tick();

        };
        Plugin.prototype.reset = function () {
            this.options.counter = 0;

        };
        Plugin.prototype.tick = function () {

                if (this.options.counter > this.options.countUpTo) {
                    //timer expired
                    this.options.onExpire($(this.element));
                }
                else {
                    if (this.options.counter > this.options.notifyAfter) {
                        $(this.element).find('span').html('<strong style="font-size: 15px; color:#ff0000;">' + this.options.counter+ ' seconds</strong>');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this.element).find('span').html('<strong style="font-size: 15px; color:#3366ff">' + this.options.counter + ' seconds</strong>');
                    }

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        this.options.counter += 1;
                        this.tick();
                    }, 1000);//calling tick function again
                }       

        };  

        $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
            return this.each(function () {
                if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                    $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
                }
            });
        };

    }(jQuery, window));
```

on document ready ::

```
$('#countdown').countup({
                    onExpire:function() {
                        alert('hi');
                    },
                    countSince:new Date(),//count from this
                    countUpTo:30,//seconds from the countSince to expire
                    notifyAfter:20
})
```

after that i want to call reset() function on $('#countdown'). how to do that? Or is there a better way to write above code? Please give me some help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boiler-plate code you created is awfully complicated.  The following HTML and JavaScript (along with jQuery) will accomplish an upward counter from 0 until a number of seconds defined by `var countTo` at which point it will print the message stored in `var successMsg`.  The reset button restarts the counter at zero.

HTML:

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
<input id="countreset" value="Reset" type="button" />​
```

JavaScript:

```
var countTo = 5; // Time to count to
var successMsg = 'hi'; // Replace count with this message at max number of seconds
function countUp() {
    var countdown = $('#countdown');
    // Turn contents into integer
    var current = parseInt(countdown.html());
    // Increment seconds
    var next = current+1;
    if (next >= countTo) {
        // If at max seconds, replace with message
        countdown.html(successMsg);                
    } else {
        // Replace seconds with next second
        countdown.html(next);
        setTimeout(countUp, 1000);
    }
}
function startCountdown() {
    var countdown = $('#countdown');
    // Set to zero seconds
    countdown.html('0');

    // Start counting
    setTimeout(countUp, 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Start the countdown
    startCountdown();
    $('#countreset').click(function() {
        // On reset button .click(), start countdown
        startCountdown();
    });
});​
```

I've put the solution up on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TxVnS/2/

**Update:**
A solution to allow for variable counter ids is here: http://jsfiddle.net/TxVnS/6/

Comment: yes, that will work. but i want to have multiple counters bind to number of elements. That why i thought about a plugin.

Comment: Hey Ninearts, your question didn't specify this so I'm not going to update the solution on StackOverflow (since I think it's better to keep it simple), but I have updated the JavaScript and HTML on jsFiddle.  Here's a link to the updated code that takes the id as an argument for both the counter and reset button: http://jsfiddle.net/TxVnS/6/